# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty x^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I calculate $\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty x^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x+1}$?

It's a follow-up question to $\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty x\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x+1}$, which I found by factoring out $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ and then looking at the sum as a derivative of a geometric series, but the same approach does not work here. I've tried manipulating $x^2$ into a form similar to $(x+1)(x-1)+1$ but it hasn't gotten me very far.

Comment: Same approach works. Differentiate like you did, multiply by the variable $t$ (too bad you used $x$ for the index), and differentiate again.

Comment: Yes, I've just realized that I can express it as a second derivative - is there a way of deleting a question?

Comment: There is a way to delete, but you might as well leave it, it may be useful for someone else.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{\verts{\mu} < 1}$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}\mu^{x} &= {\mu \over 1 - \mu} = -1 + {1 \over 1 - \mu}
\end{align}

> Derivate respect $\ds{\mu}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}x\mu^{x - 1} &={1 \over \pars{1 - \mu}^{2}}
> \quad\imp\quad\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}x\mu^{x} ={\mu \over \pars{1 - \mu}^{2}}
> \end{align}

Derivate again:
\begin{align}
\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}x^{2}\mu^{x - 1} &=-\,{1 + \mu\over \pars{1 - \mu}^{3}}
\quad\imp\quad
\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}x^{2}\mu^{x + 1}=
-\,{\mu^{2}\pars{1 + \mu}\over \pars{1 - \mu}^{3}}
\end{align}

> Replace $\ds{\mu = \half}$:
>   $$
> \color{#00f}{\large\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}x^{2}\pars{\half}^{x + 1}}=
> \left.-\,{\mu^{2}\pars{1 + \mu}\over \pars{1 - \mu}^{3}}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1/2}
> =\color{#00f}{\large 3}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is perturbation method from 'Concrete Mathematics'. Consider

$$
S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 a^{k+1}\\
S_{n+1} = S_n + (n+1)^3 a^{n+2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^3 a^{k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^3 a^{k+1} \\
=S_n +3 \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 a ^{k+1} +3 \sum_{k=1}^nka^{k+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k+1} 
$$

Obviously $S_n$ cancels out, you already know the expression for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k a^{k+1}$, so you can do the rest. Be careful with the algebra though.